# Selenium Python: Finding span nested in div with a certain css attribute

Tags: python, xml, selenium, xpath

I am trying to build a web scraper for public records. Currently my HTML has several "cards" with property information including address, and folio number. Each card has the following HTML.

```
<div class="results_record ng-scope" ng-repeat="candidate in candidatesList.candidates | orderBy:['siteAddress']">
        
        <span class="record_number ng-binding">1</span>
        
        
        <div class="record_folio ng-binding"><strong>FOLIO:</strong>           
            <span ng-click="getCandidateFolio(candidate.folio)" class="ng-binding">01-4138-159-0001</span> (Reference)
        </div>
        

    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: candidate in candidatesList.candidates | orderBy:['siteAddress'] --><div class="results_record ng-scope" ng-repeat="candidate in candidatesList.candidates | orderBy:['siteAddress']">
```

I would like to select the folio number text (i.e 01-4138-159-0001 for this example) for each card.My code is as follows with Selenium for Python and I get no results:

```
folios =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@ng-click="getCandidateFolio(candidate.folio"]')
for folio in folios:
print(folio.text)
```

Is there a better way of selecting the folio number?

Comment: Are you getting any error message? Also, you haven't closed your brackets after candidate.folio.

Comment: @RhysFlook Thanks, after closing the brackets I now get:
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@ngclick="getCandidateFolio(candidate.folio)"]"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
folios =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@ng-click="getCandidateFolio(candidate.folio)"]')

for folio in folios:
      print(folio.text)
```

There was a missing ) .Then just use .text or get_attribute('textContent') on it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With that code now I get the error message:
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@ngclick="getCandidateFolio(candidate.folio)"]"}`

Each card has 1 folio that I want to find, but I would like to find folios from all cards on the page, would find_element be the best way to go about it?

Comment: Forgot a - and find_elements would be the one then.

Comment: Still no luck, I have the same message. What find method could I use instead?

Comment: Is it in any iframes?

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Using:

```
folios =  driver.find_elements_by_class_name('record_folio')
```

and most importantly had to add a time.sleep(30) as the page had apparently not fully loaded. Thank you for the help everyone!